# Can anyone tell me how can i make more then one view through single action

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone tell me how can i make more then one view through single action in zend modular based Framework.

For example

```
$UserId    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if($UserId !='')
{    
    $userDetails =$loginObj->getUserTypeByID($UserId);
    if($userDetails == 0)
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'profile', 'default');
    else
        $usrType    = $userDetails['user_type'];
    if($usrType =='C' || $usrType =='H' )
    {
        //$this->renderScript('other-user-profile.phtml' );
        //$this->render("other-user-profile.phtml");
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer('profile/other-user-profile.phtml');
            //$this->_forward('other-user-profile.phtml','profile','default');
    }
    else
    {
           $this->render("index.phtml");
    }  
}
```

this is not working ?how to solve it?

Comment: really cant understand your query

Comment: I guess you like developing your questions. I cannot decrypt this.

Comment: Please, provide meaningful and understandable question!

Comment: Which view is rendering now?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in several ways, like using [Partial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) view helper.

*EDIT:* In response to your code segment:

You better use [ViewRenderer Action Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer). Check Example #11 in this page. The comments inside the code are pretty self explanatory. I suggest you take care about the script path.

```
// Bar controller class, foo module:
class Foo_BarController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        // Render 'bar/form.phtml' instead of 'bar/add.phtml'
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer('form');
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        // Render 'bar/form.phtml' instead of 'bar/edit.phtml'
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setScriptAction('form');
    }

    public function processAction()
    {
        // do some validation...
        if (!$valid) {
            // Render 'bar/form.phtml' instead of 'bar/process.phtml'
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('form');
            return;
        }

        // otherwise continue processing...
    }

}
```